# How to get the display full name of the file owner given the user name (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, scanning

I am trying to scan the owner of the file but not in the "domain\username" format but instead I want to approach the AD and get the full name as the output. The code as I am trying to get the output is as following:

```
$Output = ForEach($Row in $LocContent){
      Get-ChildItem $Row.drivePath -Force -Recurse |
          Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$NumberOfDays) |
                Where-Object {($_.Extension -in $Extensions)} | 
                    Where-Object {$_.length/$SizeOfFile -gt 1} | 
                      Select-Object -Property @{N='File Basename';E={$_.BaseName}}, 
                          @{N='File Extension';E={$_.Extension}},
                          @{N='size(MB)';E={[Math]::Round(($_.Length/1024kb),2)}},
                               Directory, 
                          @{Name="Owner";Expression={([adsi]"WinNT://(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner),user").fullname}},
                               CreationTime, 
                               LastWriteTime, 
                          @{N='Last Created Within (Number of Days)';E={$NumberOfDays}},
                          @{N="Location";E={$Row.country}}
}
```

The line "Name="Owner" is where I want to generate the full name of the net user but it doesn't output anything in the end. How can I fix that so that it will shower the name of the file creater. Thanks!

Comment: Does it help to change `Get-ACL $_.Fullname` to `Get-ACL $($_.Fullname)`?

Comment: Looks like you are missing an opening bracket just before the `Get-ACL`. I think it should be `@{Name="Owner";Expression={([adsi]"WinNT://((Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner),user").fullname}}`

Comment: @H.Wang Do you EVER accept an answer or let people know their comments have put you in the right direction?? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thank you @boxdog and it looks like there are still more other than that to make the code work :)